# Different behaviour of systemctl suspend when executed via i3 wm key binding

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, lightdm, i3

I am using the i3 tiling windows manager in combination with light-locker to lock the screen.

Light-locker displays a lock message on the locked TTY and shows the password screen on a second TTY.

When closing the notebook lid or executing `systemctl suspend` from a terminal emulator, the lock messages appears for a short time, then the system goes into S3 state. On resume, the lock message is visible for a short time again, then light-locker switches to the password entry-TTY, which is the desired behaviour.

The problem occurs when I bind the systemctl command to a specific key via the i3 config file like this:

```
bindsym s exec --no-startup-id systemctl suspend, mode "default"
```

When pressing $mod + s, the screen turns black immediately, not showing the lock message.

On resume, the screen turns on, displaying the unlocked desktop for a half second, then the lock messages flashes for the fraction of a second and then the password entry-TTY is shown.

This behaviour is not acceptable, as it exposes the desktop after suspending the computer, even the desktop is only visible for a short time.

My guess is, that when using bash to execute `systemctl suspend`, the command takes longer time or sth. like that, making it possible for light-locker to switch to the lock message before the system suspends.

How can I avoid or circumvent the different behaviour of the key binding?

Comment: Use a script or something that explicitly locks the screen then calls suspend.

Comment: Unfortunately, after calling the command to explictly lock the screen, the suspend command gets not executed.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve problem by using the following commands:

```
(sleep 0.5 && systemctl suspend) &
```

It would be interesting to know, why exactly the sleep command is needed to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Did you have that '&' fork in there at all before?  If i3's `exec` waits, that would affect behaviour.  Evidently light locker was catching a signal *after* the suspend resumes, as if it and i3 were suspended until the `exec` completed, whereas when run from a shell that is not an issue.  Forking it off allows them to resume and catch the signal from suspend without it being deferred.